# correct way to check if a record exists in (mysql) table

Tags: mysql, c

To simply verify if a record exists in the table.
would this be the most optimal correct method ?

( if i were to also return an integer 1 or 0 )

```
char *qu;
qu = malloc(300);

sprintf(qu, "select 1 from account where un='%s' and pw='%s' limit 1",u,p);
mysql_query(co, qu);

res =  mysql_use_result(co);
row = mysql_fetch_row(res);

if(row){
return "exists";
}else{
return "no";
}
```

i also tried **row[0]**, that will cause problems when there is no records found.  ( or perhaps even when found )..

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way of doing this is:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM account WHERE un=? and pw=?)
```

Note that I've used bind variables. You should always use them to parameterise your query for safety from SQL injection, rather than using `sprintf`.

References:

[13.2.10.6 Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

[27.8.9 C API Prepared Statement Data Structures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-prepared-statement-data-structures.html)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like this:

```
while( row = mysql_fetch_row( res ) ) return atoi( row[ 0 ]); 
return 0; // or "no"
```